Increase the width of the tendril plot generated via Tendril package
I generated the Tendril plot via Tendril package, however i am unable to increase the width of the plot, i tried plot margin but that does not give satisfactory results. Could you please help me how to increase the width of the plot
library(Tendril)
library(Tplyr)
library(dplyr)

adae <- Tplyr::tplyr_adae %>% filter(SAFFL=='Y' & TRTAN %in% c(0, 54)) %>% select(USUBJID, TRTA, ASTDY, AEDECOD) %>% 
  arrange(USUBJID, TRTA, AEDECOD, ASTDY) %>% 
  rename_all(tolower) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

aelist <- table(adae$aedecod, adae$trta) %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(Var1) %>% filter(all(Freq>0)) %>% distinct() %>% 
  pull(Var1)

adae <- adae %>% filter(aedecod %in% aelist)

SubjList <- adae %>% select(usubjid, trta) %>% distinct() %>% as.data.frame()

data <- Tendril(mydata = adae,
                rotations = 1,
                AEfreqThreshold = 1,
                Tag = "EudraCT",
                Treatments = c("Placebo", "Xanomeline Low Dose"),
                Unique.Subject.Identifier = "usubjid",
                Terms = "aedecod",
                Treat = "trta",
                StartDay = "astdy",
                SubjList = SubjList,
                SubjList.subject = "usubjid",
                SubjList.treatment = "trta",
                compensate_imbalance_groups = T,
                filter_double_events = T,
                suppress_warnings = TRUE
)

tendril_plot <- plot(data) +theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 1, r = 1, b = 1, l = 1, unit = "pt"))

print(tendril_plot)



Try with ggplot2::coord_fixed(ratio = 0.01) or whatever value for ratio the works for your use case.
Ignore the warning message:
Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.


plot(data) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.1)




<sup>Created on 2024-06-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>
 

